How to calculate HOSVD of matrix of variables
I can calculate the SVD of a normal 2x2 matrix of variables like this
(*Define the symbolic variables*)matrix = {{a, b}, {c, d}};

(*Compute the SVD*)
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[matrix];

(*Display the results*)
U // MatrixForm
S // MatrixForm
V // MatrixForm

And I can compute the HOSVD of a tensor of just numbers like this
(*Perform the Tucker decomposition and store the result*)
result = 
  ResourceFunction[
    "TuckerDecomposition"][{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}];

(*Display the result nicely*)
Grid[{{"Core Tensor:", MatrixForm[result[[1]]]}, {"Factor Matrices:", 
   TableForm[result[[2]]]}}, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]

But when I just put variables instead
(*Perform the Tucker decomposition and store the result*)
result = 
  ResourceFunction[
    "TuckerDecomposition"][{{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}];

(*Display the result nicely*)
Grid[{{"Core Tensor:", MatrixForm[result[[1]]]}, {"Factor Matrices:", 
   TableForm[result[[2]]]}}, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]

it says . How can I fix this?

TuckerDecomposition uses SingularValueDecomposition and from the help of this: "gives the singular value decomposition for a numerical matrix ". Therefore you need a numerical matrix, not a symbolic one.

The "symbolic" SVD is sort of a unicorn. That is to say, it does not really exist, and we just pretend it does and make pictures to show what it might look like.
